# OpenCV compiler error when using Stitcher under iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, compiler-construction

Whenever I try to use the OpenCV Stitcher class in iOS and I include the stitcher-header ( #include ) I end up with a compile error "Expected '{'" in exposure_compensate.hpp. Apparently the line
    enum { NO, GAIN, GAIN_BLOCKS };
is causing some sort of error.

I am very new to openCV but using other functions like filter2d() work as expected. How can I resolve this?

Comment: how did u fix that Please

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

then

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Update: this answer only highlights the bare minimum fix of the problem, and perhaps the root cause: order of dependencies. Please refer to other answers for better code / setup that you put in your project.

Comment: This saved me after hours of debugging.

Comment: For a more robust solution, you should definitely use a PCH file as explained in the other answers.

Answer (score 8):

In your project, create a Prefix Header, MyProject.pch, and set it in your project's build settings.

Then within that pch file, do something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#   include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#   include <opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp>
#   include <opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp>
#else
#   import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#   import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#   import <Availability.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem. As G. Führ ensure you include the opencv headers first. The easiest way to do this is add:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

near the top of the apps "Appname-Prefix.pch" header. This is a precompiled header and makes it easy to guarantee that your opencv header will be included before any of the apple headers.

```
//
//  Prefix header
//
//  The contents of this file are implicitly included at the beginning of every source file.
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

This means you won't accidentally include an apple header before this anywhere else in the app.

Comment: this is the exact answer.
<This means you won't accidentally include an apple header before this anywhere else in the app.>

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I solved editing directly the opencv-framework files involved (in your case `compensate.hpp`) and comment from them the definition of the `NO` enum case definition. In this case the file was `blender.hpp`, but `compensate.hpp` has the same structure
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This is kinda awful  but for my scenario, where OpenCV was included via our library and none of the suggestions worked for the app using it, it saved a lot of time getting a demo up and running. As this is an internal spike I can live with it for now.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by importing any Apple headers before those of OpenCV, as mentioned in the beginning of the header:

```
#if defined(NO)
#  warning Detected Apple 'NO' macro definition, it can cause build conflicts. Please, include this header before any Apple headers.
#endif
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you mean importing Apple headers AFTER `opencv` headers? It's `include this header before any Apple headers`, and I tried `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` then `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create a vertical image stitching app with openCV, error show as screenshot below. It is from `exposure_compensate.hpp` and `blenders.hpp`. From the error description, the top file is ../CVWrapper.mm, which is in my project instead of openCV pod project.

As above guys said, there is some conflict issue between C++ and Apple MACRO. And we should put C++ header above Apple header.

First, I try a workaround from internet, which said "replace `NO` with `NO_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATOR = 0`". This worked, but it modified openCV source code, I don't want to do that because I will not do version control on Pod files, then if other guys clone my repo/project, they will need to do the same modification on those source code.

Then, I follow the error message in Xcode, I did following changes in my `CVWrapper.mm` file. After that, those two error disappear.

```
// Before change
#import "CVWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"
#import "stitching.h"
#import "UIImage+Rotate.h"

// After change
#import "stitching.h"
#import "CVWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"
#import "UIImage+Rotate.h"
```

[image]